# What is the effect on insulin sensitivity after sudden breaking of a low carb diet?

Tags: nutrition, insulin, ketosis

What is the effect on the amount of insulin secreted after ingestion of a high carb diet after being on a low carb diet for some time.Will the amount of insulin secreted be too high or too low and why?

Comment: Welcome to HealthSE! Please feel invited to take the [tour](https://health.stackexchange.com/tour) and to read the [help documents](https://health.stackexchange.com/help).